# Adding URL in HTML class

Tags: html, css, url

How do you add a URL link in a class?

```
<div class="social-profile">
        <li class="facebook">
          <a  href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="twitter">
          <a href="http://www.twitter.com"></a>
        </li>
    </div>
```

My CSS sheet has Facebook and twitter icons that I need to link to.

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: Define "link to".  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to style an element based on its `href` value?

```
[href="http://www.facebook.com"] {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are searching for is the [background image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) in css so you would need the following css:

```
.facebook {
   background-image: url("url/to/facebook.gif");
 }

.twitter{
   background-image: url("url/to/twitter.gif");
 }
```

Although I would be tempted to put that on the `a` tag and make sure it fills the `li`.